# Can I trigger a workflow in SharePoint 2007 whenever a URL is visited

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, workflow

I have a flash program sitting in SharePoint 2007, and I'd like to trigger a workflow (to send an email to the logged in user), but I don't really have any hooks to do that.

Can I reliably start a workflow by opening up a (fixed) URL?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can if you write a HTTP Handler that checks the request and starts the workflow.  This article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457204(v=office.12).aspx can get you started.

Comment: Thanks, even if that's what I was worried about (the client's IT dept is going to push hard against deploying custom code)